# tidy rearrange within rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

Is there a tidier way than the following to "rearrange" values based on a second column?

The df contains responses to likert questions that were presented in a randomised order in a questionnaire. The "item" columns contain which item was presented, the "response" columns contain the answers.

The goal is to have a df where response columns are sorted by the item column for each participant (row)?

Initial Format:

```
 ##     id  item.1  response.1  item.2  response.2  item.3  response.3  ... item.x   respons.x
 ##  1  1     2        5           1        4          3         2      
 ##  2  2     3        4           1        5          2         4       
 ## ...
 ##  i
```

Desired Format:

```
 ##    id  order_1 reponse_1 order_2 reponse_2  order_3 reponse_3 ...  order_x   reponse_x
 ## 1  1     2         4         1        5        3        2          
 ## 2  2     2         5         3        4        1        4          
 ## ...
 ## i
```

So far my tidiest approach is the following:

```
df <- data_frame(
  id = 1:4,
  item.1 = c(2,3,2,4),
  response.1 = c(4,1,3,2),
  item.2 = c(1,2,1,1),
  response.2 = c(5,4,5,4),
  item.3 = c(3,4,3,2),
  response.3 = c(1,2,2,5),
  item.4 = c(4,1,4,3),
  response.4 = c(2,2,2,1)
)

df_long <- df %>%
  unite(col = one, ends_with(".1"), sep = ";") %>%
  unite(col = two, ends_with(".2"), sep = ";") %>%
  unite(col = three, ends_with(".3"), sep = ";") %>%
  unite(col = four, ends_with(".4"), sep = ";") %>%
  gather(key = "number", value = "item_response", c(one, two, three, four)) %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  separate(item_response, into = c("item", "response"))
```

This initial step could have also be done with less lines of code with the base function reshape().

```
reshape(df, varying = names(df[,-1]), idvar = "id", direction = "long")
```

I would however prefer a tidyverse solution. I found this thread (https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/150) with a discussion of having a multi-gather, but it seems that there hasn't been a final solution yet.

In the end I do not even want my data to be in long format and therefore need to spread it back to wide.

```
df_final <- df_long %>%
  unite(col = order_response, c(number,response), sep = ";") %>%
  spread(item, order_response) %>%
  separate(`1`, into = c("order_1", "response_1"), sep = ";") %>%
  separate(`2`, into = c("order_2", "response_2"), sep = ";") %>%
  separate(`3`, into = c("order_3", "response_3"), sep = ";") %>%    
  separate(`4`, into = c("order_4", "response_4"), sep = ";")
```

In the df I am using I however have 40 items instead of 4, which adds quiet some lines to the code. Is there a tidier way? I have not worked with purr a lot, but is this something purr could help with? To me the problem seems quiet straightforward and I am suprised that I could not find a better solution for it so far.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "sorted by item" wouldn't that mean that order_1 is always 1, order_2 always 2 and so forth?

Comment: It's not obvious what the transformation is to get from your initial format to your desired output

Comment: I am not sure how I can explain it differently with words, but if you have a look at what I ourlined with initial format and compare it with the desired format, it should become clear.